# Import freestyle line style from other .blend file

Tags: freestyle

I know you can import other stuff like object from another .blend file. I am wondering if you can do the same of the line styles and how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can import/append /link the freestyle
save the file with freestyle
When import / append with the with the other folder of texture lamp mesh object you get the folder of Freestylelinestyle

Open the folder and append/link

In the Render -> activate the freestyle option

After import/append under Render Layer in properties panel -> Under Freestyle Line style select the line from the drop down.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Are we able to store these imported styles if we delete the original .blend?